# average hop yields

Tags: beer, hops, growing-hops

i'm looking to plant my own hops in my yard (yes i know i'm late. researching for next year). however, i'm trying to figure out roughly how many say cascade rhizomes i would need to make this worth my effort. meaning, if i get 5-8 rhizomes, would that yield enough to make a typical homebrew? i understand the first year or so has a low yield which is ok. at this point, getting ideas and numbers together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If growing conditions are optimal you'll get plenty of hops.  I have 3 varieties growing and my Fuggles is the most dominant.  2nd year I had close to 2 lbs dried and packaged off a single rhizome so 5-8 rhizomes will get you plenty of picking opportunities.  I've read on average you can expect a healthy rhizome will produce 1.5 to 2 lbs in a good season.

Comment: so a good year of 1.5-2lbs, i should be able to make plenty of good beer. just so i have an idea or maybe i'm just curious but a small craft beer shop making a single batch are looking at tons needed?

Comment: Some quick match and a direct scaling of the recipe I just brewed which called for 8 oz of hops would result in the need for 378 lbs of hops for a 120 bbl tank.  Not perfect science there but a ballpark of what a hoppier brew would need on a craft scale.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on the variety and your weather.  I live in the middle of prime hop growing country.  I have one Cascade plant that's about 12 years old now.  I get anywhere from 20-27 lb. of wet hops each year from it.  Enough that it's a hassle to pick, dry, and vacuum package them.

Comment: yea i figured weather/variety would be important here. just trying to get a general idea. averages. i'm in nj right on the coast. basically between 6-7 on the hardiness.

Comment: In general, the closer you are to the 45th parallel, the better your yield will be.